# Override declared var type in typedefinition file

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I was looking for this but it seems more problematic.

In external library type definitions file there is a line...

```
declare var analytics: SegmentAnalytics.AnalyticsJS;
```

Now I want to make small change in this type definition and mark that this variable can be undefined in some environment when I'm running app. So I wanted to redeclare it to this...

```
import '@types/segment-analytics';
declare var analytics: SegmentAnalytics.AnalyticsJS | undefined;
```

But from some reason the VS Code don't work with this new definitions. Is this possible to redeclare variables like this with my own `*.d.ts` file in `src` folder?

Comment: "*don't work with this new definitions*" - are you getting an error? Or do you mean that they don't apply?

Comment: VS Studio don't see this new type. It refers to the original one from `import` only